# getting error while creating a react app using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a react app using these two commands .Here are the two commands.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

I am getting this error on my terminal .

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...org/jest/-/jest-20.
0.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-01T16_28
_34_038Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts
 has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
```

Comment: You should add the contents of the log as well as the contents of your package.json

Comment: Hey i don't see package.json file as no such file has been created .

Comment: It was deleted since npm install failed - see the last line in your question... Post the log file.